# Enviar HTML por JSON con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, json

Tengo este HTML que genero con la funcion de php selectHorarios()

```
<option>13:15</option>
<option>13:30</option>
<option>13:45</option> 
<option>14:00</option>
```

Que lo envío con este archivo PHP

```
require "config/config.php";
require "listadoTurnosFunc.php";
$dia = 

    $datos = array(
    'fecha' =>selectHorarios($_POST['medico'],$_POST['fecha'],$_POST['horadesde'],$_POST['horahasta']);
    );

    echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Y lo recibo con esta función de javascript para actualizar un select de horarios

```
 $("#fecha").on("change",function(){
selectHorarios = {
      fecha: $('#fecha').val(),
      medico: $('#medico').val(),
      horadesde: $('#horadesde').val(),
      horahasta: $('#horahasta').val()
  }; 
$.post('buscadorSelectHorarios.php', selectHorarios, function(data, 
textStatus) {
  if(textStatus=="success"){
    $("#fecha").html(data.fecha);
  }
}, 
"json");
```

Pero el Json me devuelve

```
{"fecha":"13:15<\/option>13:30<\/option>13:45<\/option>14:00<\/option>"}
```

existe una manera de pasar el html por json en php para que tome los caracteres de html como "/<>"  ?

Comment: ajuro lo tienes que recibir por json? si solo le haces un echo sin el json_encode te funcionaria de una

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta colocando tu `json_encode` así:

```
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Con esto tu respuesta sería algo como:

```
"\u003Coption\u003E13:15\u003C\/option\u003E\n \u003Coption\u003E13:30\u003C\/option\u003E\n \u003Coption\u003E13:45\u003C\/option\u003E \n \u003Coption\u003E14:00\u003C\/option\u003E"
```

Puedes verlo [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$horarios%20=%20%22%3Coption%3E13:15%3C/option%3E%5Cn%20%3Coption%3E13:30%3C/option%3E%5Cn%20%3Coption%3E13:45%3C/option%3E%5Cn%20%3Coption%3E14:00%3C/option%3E%22;%5Cn%5Cnecho%20json_encode($horarios,%20JSON_HEX_QUOT%20%7C%20JSON_HEX_TAG);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn).

Y luego en tu **ajax** simplemente haces esto:

```
$.post('buscadorSelectHorarios.php', selectHorarios, function(data, 
textStatus) {
  if(textStatus=="success"){
    $("#fecha").html(data);
  }
}, 
"json");
```

```js
var fechaJson = '\u003Coption\u003E13:15\u003C\/option\u003E\n \u003Coption\u003E13:30\u003C\/option\u003E\n \u003Coption\u003E13:45\u003C\/option\u003E \n \u003Coption\u003E14:00\u003C\/option\u003E';

$("#fecha").html(fechaJson);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Horario:</label> <select id="fecha"></select>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvió perfecto lo adapte a mi código y no tuve drama